# Integer doesn't act like a real Object?

Tags: java, function

First, I am sorry for my English. It is not my main language.

```
class Car {
    private Integer x;

    public Car(){
        this.x = new Integer(5);
    }

    public Integer getInt(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car();
        Integer x = car.getInt();
        // Here is what annoying me. I want to change the value of car.x only with getInt()
        x += 4;
        system.out.println(""+car.x);
        //This will print 5, when i want it to print 6.
    }
}
```

This is only a concept. I need to change the value of an Integer THIS way for my project.
It seems to be impossible, but i may miss something.

What I mean is that it could be very helpful if i could do something like this:

```
Integer x = car.getInt();
x.setValue(9);
```

That's the problem of using Java.
I love Java, but in c++ I could just use the pointer everywhere.

If you wonder why I ever need to use this method, it is because that I have these 2 functions:

```
private Rectangle2D.Double rect;
private Vector3D position;
```

`rect.x` should have the same value as `position.x`.
Then, every time I adjust one of these values, I have to change them both.
Each of these functions is used for different methods. 
I use the rect to render and I use the position to calculate..

Thank you very much!

Comment: there is usually no need to use `Integer` over `int`. `int` is more efficient & less error prone (no `null`, `==` comparisons work, ...)

Comment: I guess so. Until this moment, I tought im able to use Integer in the way i described earlier.

Comment: I still have to problem of having the need to duplicate my data over 2 objects. Rectangle2D.Double, Vector3D

Comment: And it's impossible to assign the same object to them (`Vector3D` takes primitive `double` only, so no object at all). Whenever you want to change the value you have to assign it to both manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java the `Integer` class is [*immutable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so you'll never be able to change the value of one of its instances. It's like that by design, so many instances of the same `Integer` can be shared safely.

Comment: Ok then, It seems to answer my question. But any alternative?

Comment: @Nirock perhaps creating your own `MutableInteger`? or defining an `Integer[]` of size `1`, there you can change the value at the `0` index. But really, that doesn't seem like a good idea - it smells like a design problem. If the same integer happens to be shared across the application and suddenly it changes value in all the places it's used, you'll have a really hard bug to track

Comment: @Nirock and by the way, _why_ are you using an `Integer`? it'd be better to use a plain `int`, and if necessary write a `setInt()` in your class to modify the attribute.

Comment: Im not using this class really. It was just to clear my mind. I tought that Integer is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a setInt(Integer i) method to your Car if you want to modify the x attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that `Integer` objects are immutable.  What you need to do is this:

```
    car.setInt(car.getInt() + 4);
```

What is actually happening in your code is as follows:

```
    Integer x = car.getInt();
```

This gets the reference to the `Integer` object ...

```
    x += 4;
```

This is equivalent to this.

```
    int temp = x.intValue();
    int temp = temp + 4;
    x = Integer.valueOf(temp);
```

In other words `x += 4` is creating a new object and assigning it to the local variable `x`.  That new object is not being communicated back to the `Car.x` instance variable.

---

There are a couple of other alternaive solutions:

- Get rid of the `x` local variable, and have the `main` method operate directly on `car.x`.  (This is stylistically questionable, but your example is pretty artificial anyway.)
- Use (maybe write) a mutable integer holder class instead of `Integer`.  However, that will mean that you *won't* be able to use auto-boxing / auto-unboxing; i.e. `x += 4;` won't be legal any more.

---

> .... I was looking for alternative. something like x.setValue(9);

There isn't one.  The primitive wrapper types are immutable.  A set operation ... or anything else that violates the "immutablity" invariant is impossible<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - Strictly speaking that's not correct.  There *is* a way to do it.  However, if you did change the "value" of an `Integer` object, there is a big risk that you'd break all sorts of other things in the JVM.  The `Integer` class in particular implements an optimization whereby autoboxing *reuses* existing `Integer` instances.  So if you managed to change an `Integer` object that holds 8 to hold 9 instead ... you could be changing *lots of other* 8s to 9.  Ouch!!!</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the information.
I'm actually aware of that thing, but i was looking for alternative. something like x.setValue(9);

Comment: I am actually sorry that I am not able to tick 2 answers.

Comment: And btw, thats what I want it to do. I want it to change all of the instances of this object to hold 9 instead of 8.

Comment: In that case, you need to use a mutable integer holder class; i.e. not Integer.  AND, you have to make sure that all relevant `Car` objects have references to the same (shared) integer holder.